# Is there a shortkey to focus the YouTube comment input?

Tags: youtube, keyboard-shortcuts

Suppose i’m watching a YouTube video and I want to focus to comment input immediately. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no shortcut to jump to the comment section. All keyboard shortcuts that YouTube has are listed when pressing <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>?</kbd> (on QWERTY keyboards).

[image: Shift+? screenshot]